# Asymptotic approximation of the arctangent?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

That is, I am looking for an algebraic function $f(x)$ that approximates $\arctan x$ for large values of $x$.

The approximation could be reasonably modest -- perhaps something like

$$\tan (f(x)) = \frac{\pi}{4} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

Comment: You could be interested in a recent work of mine: http://files.ele-math.com/preprints/mia-3585-pre.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following

$$\arctan(x) + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

The series for $\arctan(x)$ is

$$\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\ldots$$

Now substitute $\frac1x$ to get the result

$$\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3}-\frac{1}{5x^5} +\ldots$$

So for large values of $x$

$$\arctan(x)\sim\frac{\pi}{2}$$

which is logical, because $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\arctan\left(x\right)
={\pi \over 2}\,{\rm sgn}\left(x\right) - \arctan\left(1 \over x\right)
\approx{\pi \over 2}\,{\rm sgn}\left(x\right) - {1 \over x}\,,\qquad
\left\vert\,x\,\right\vert \gg 1
$$

Answer (score 5):

This approximation converges much faster:
$$
\arctan(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{{{a}_{n}}\left(x\right)}{a_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)+b_{n}^{2}\left(x\right)}},
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
& a_1(x)=2/x,\\ 
& b_1(x)=1,\\ 
& a_n(x)=a_{n-1}(x)\,\left(1-4/x^2\right)+4b_{n-1}(x)/x,\\ 
& b_n(x)=b_{n-1}(x)\,\left(1-4/x^2\right)-4a_{n-1}(x)/x.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, by taking the first term only, the following asymptotic approximation can be used:
$$
\arctan\left(x\right)
={\pi \over 2}\,{\rm sgn}\left(x\right) - \arctan\left(1 \over x\right)
\approx \frac{\pi}{2}{\rm sgn}(x)-\frac{4 x}{4 x^2+1}\,,\qquad
\left\vert\,x\,\right\vert \gg 1.
$$

Comment: +1 Where is the summation for $\arctan x$ from?

Comment: Wikipedia, approximations of pi.